# When to use StorageDoubleMap `clear_prefix` vs `drain_prefix`?

Tags: storage, map, cleanup, remove-all, storagemap

Hey Substrate community,

there are two different methods to remove multiple items for one specific first key from a `StorageDoubleMap`. There is [`clear_prefix`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageDoubleMap.html#method.clear_prefix) and [`drain_prefix`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/storage/types/struct.StorageDoubleMap.html#method.drain_prefix). `clear_prefix` provides additional information with a cursor, that needs to be used for the case, that the map is not fully cleaned. But isn't `drain_prefix` the same functionality with less information as `clear_prefix`?

So I mean I can check with `drain_prefix`, if there are items left to delete. I could query `if <StorageItem<T>>::drain_prefix(first_key).take(1).next().is_none()`. Sure, this requires one additional read. Is this the reason why `clear_prefix` exists too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference to me is if it returns a closure.

When you just want to remove it:

```rust
Foo::clear_prefix();
```

<sup>Note: these are pseudo code</sup>

When you want to interact with the removed item:

```rust
Foo::darin_prefix().iter().for_each(|removed_item| {
    Bar::insert(removed_item.hash(), removed_item);
});
```

<sup>Note: these are pseudo code</sup>